# ImproperlyConfigured at /admin/

Tags: django, python-2.7, admin

I'm currently on the 2nd Django Tutorial by Hacked Existence on youtube.  It is helping me to learn and I would like to continue to do so.  I understand that the video is posted about a year ago so it's a little out of date.  So I have some questions.

I created an app called beers

```
python manage.py sqlall beer
```

In minute 13, he edits admin.py as such:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from beer.models import Beer, Brewery

class BeerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('name')}

admin.site.register(Beer, BeerAdmin)
admin.site.register(Brewery)
```

This modification leads to an error:

> ImproperlyConfigured at /admin/
>
> > 'BeerAdmin.prepopulated_fields['slug']' must be a list or tuple.

How do I fix this problem, and why did this same code work fine for his system.
This message is displayed at

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/
```

which leads to the next question,

On my browser,

[HackedExistence link](http://video1.hackedexistence.com/)
opens up the Apache 2 Test Page
and the localhost link opens up the Django Administrator page nicely (well, it did until the above edit).

But he sets it up so that hacked existence link loads up the Django Admin page.

I have no problem with my setup if it does not lead to further issues.  But I would like to know what different steps are needed for setting it up that way with the versions that I'm working with.

> Python 2.7.3, Django 1.4.1, Apache 2.2.22 (Unix)

I'm working with OS X 10.6.8.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I made a separate [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12834133/localhost-vs-video1-hackedexistence-com) for the second part of my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your definition to

```
prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('name',)}
```

Note: the comma after `'name'`, without the comm its interpreted as string object not a tuple  or list.

Answer (score 0):

This is a "gotcha" that trips up many Python newbies: in a tuple, the essential syntactical element is the comma. The parentheses are actually optional. You can read more about that [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TupleSyntax)