# Localhost vs. video1.hackedexistence.com

Tags: django, apache, python-2.7

I'm following  through the Django Tutorials by HackedExistence on youtube.
Since the video is about a year old, I assume that the version differences may contribute to this problem.  I'm currently on the 2nd video but this issue arose since the first.

On my browser,

```
http://video1.hackedexistence.com/
```

This link opens up the Apache 2 Test Page, and the localhost link opens up the Django Administrator page nicely.

But he sets it up so that the [hacked existence link](http://video1.hackedexistence.com/) loads up the Django Admin page.

How is he able to achieve this? and what steps are needed for setting it up that way with the versions that I'm working with.

```
Python 2.7.3, Django 1.4.1, Apache 2.2.22 (Unix)
```

Running on OS X 10.6.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

video1.hackedexistence.com is (presumably) a domain under the control of HackedExistence, and it's showing an Apache 2 test page because the server it's pointing to is not configured to show anything else. You have no control over this domain or the server it is pointing to, so you can't affect it directly.

It doesn't have anything to do with different versions of python, django, apache, or anything else; it's likely that HackedExistence chose to move on to something else, is no longer maintaining his site (or at least the content on that subdomain of it) and his tutorial now no longer works as a result.

The closest you can come is add an entry to your `/private/etc/hosts` file (on OSX) so that video1.hackedexistence.com resolves to 127.0.0.1 (i.e. localhost, your own computer), but this is almost certainly not what you're after. For example, if you do this, everybody else will still see the test page you're seeing now, because the /etc/hosts file is just telling your computer to treat the video1.hackedexistence.com domain as if it's pointing to your computer.

For learning web development, you can safely completely disregard this and can continue to test on your local computer.

When it comes to deploying the website for other people to view and use, you will need to buy a domain (e.g. at http://namecheap.com/), get some hosting (for python/django hosting I can recommend [WebFaction](http://webfaction.com/) , or you can use [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/)'s free plan), and follow the [Django deployment instructions in the official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/) (or the documentation provided by the hosting provider you choose). My advice is to focus on learning web development and get something working before you spend money on any hosting.

Comment: I assuemd that it was a local directory since he defined STATIC_ROOT = /he/sites/video1.hackedexistence.com/htdocs/static/  in settings.py  but now i'm thinking that it was a webserver that he was working with.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the videos, but I'm assuming that the author of the book owns (or owned at the time) the hackedexistence.com domain name, and had it pointing to his server so that it would be able to interpret the Django App and serve it up to public requests ... and now it looks like that configuration doesn't exist any more.

If you're asking what I think you want to ask, "how can I get a Django app viewable on the public web," well, there are lots of ways to go about doing this. If your server is Apache, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/ is the way to go. Google could help you find the similar docs for other servers. Lots of answers on stack overflow as well.

If instead you're asking a different question, namely, "how can I get this app on my local machine to be viewable via some method other than localhost" (and you don't have a server), well, the answer is you'd have to get a domain that points to your local machine -- this is a question that has lots of answers elsewhere. One thing to be aware of is that Django through Apache on Mac OS X isn't terribly simple, as it requires manually installing mod_wsgi, but it's not overly difficult either. Here's Google's top link (a bit old but still relevant): http://jessenoller.com/2009/07/24/django-mod_wsgi-apache-and-os-x-do-it/

And finally, if you're asking how you can get your app to show up at hacked existence, well ... buy that domain and see the above paragraph. :)